# How can I filter the elements of a Swift Sequence that successfully cast to some type?

Tags: swift

I sometimes want to pull out all the elements from a sequence that are of a specific type and return them as a sequence of that type (like C#/LINQ's [`IEnumerable.OfType<TResult>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)). I've been doing this with something like:

```
list.filter { $0 is SomeType }.map { $0 as! SomeType }
```

or:

```
list.map { $0 as? SomeType }.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
```

which both feel a bit awkward and repeat the type check. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compactMap(_:)` is what you want. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap):

> Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

So for your purposes you'd use it like this:

```
list.compactMap { $0 as? SomeType }
```

<sub>If you want Swift3 version then see edit history</sub>